# Safer alternatives to Li-ion battery packs while experimentation/development

Tags: power-supply, batteries, lithium-ion, brushless-dc-motor

I am developing a quadcopter from scratch (mainly the flight controller part) and at times I need to connect the whole system to a power supply that can sustain high currents for testing. I have the dev boards that I am developing with on a breadboard and I feel really uneasy when plugging in the Li-ion battery pack to the breadboard through a power distribution board. I already have messed up power connection (inverted it) once and most probably a protective diode on my dev board (weact blackpill) blew and the 5 V rail doesn't work anymore. I know a bench power supply is the perfect equipment for the job here, but they are expensive for me (for now at least). Is there a safer alternative so I can peacefully test if my PID controller works? For now I am using a fuse but few contacts are still exposed and still is a potential hazard. Is there any advanced current limiting devices other than fuse? I am mainly concerned about the fire hazard here, not so much worried about killing components.

Comment: How tight are your supply voltage requirements? If you are just worried about the battery fire risk, one alternative would be motorbike lead acid starter batteries. Which can supply high current at nominally 6V.

Comment: This would work better if you clarify what "high currents" means for you

Comment: @user1937198 I actually have considered that. I will be on the lookout for one. I need 12V because the motors are rated for 3S packs.

Comment: 12V is even easier. Just a bog standard car starter battery. Any car maintenance supplier should stock them.

Comment: @Maple I don't really know, the esc's are rated for 30A but I doubt that much current is needed for just testing the pid. I think I have seen those generic 2212 motors drawing far less than 10A nominally on some testing videos on youtube. I'll have to check.

Comment: @user1937198 Thanks, I'll try that if I find one reasonably priced.

Comment: Please edit this information into the question.

Comment: You can get DC circuit breakers designed for solar panels and battery applications. Something like a 32 Amp is probably suitable.

Answer (score 0):

This is just an idea for a current limiter. I'm having trouble with CircuitLab. Now it says "Your free evaluation of SmartWires has expired". And components and wires seem to be disconnected. :(

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fJHL6Z.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

OK, here is the LTspice simulation, shown with the limiting resistor (R1 in LTspice) of 50 milliOhms, for a current limit of 11.81 A. The load is stepped for RL = 10 and 100 milliohms and 1 and 10 ohms. This circuit will limit the current, but the series pass PNP transistor will dissipate up to 12 * 12 = 144 W. It should be used in conjunction with a circuit breaker or fuse. A latching feature could also be added, along with a fault indicator (LED or audible beeper).

[image: Current Limiter]

Here is a simulation with a latch and an "output good" LED indicator.

[image: Circuit with latch and LED]

Answer (score 0):

Well first of all - you need to specify how much current you need. Comments suggest ~10A, so I'll work with that.

While a 10A lab/bench supply is not cheap, there are cheap DPS5005-style units (check ebay, Aliexpress, etc.) that can provide a **regulated** 10 or 20A supply from whatever you have to hand - things like old laptop PSU's (often ~19v at ~100W+) or PC ATX power supplies (12v @ 10A would not be uncommon), old server PSU's (12v @50A is not rare) can be found for almost nothing and can provide lots of power for cheap.